# Cron Curl - using an encrypted password?

Tags: .htaccess, curl, cron

Example:

```
30 9 * * * /usr/bin/curl -u username:password http://www.mydomain.com/protectedfolder/myscript
```

Can and should I use an encrypted password here, the same as in the .htaccess file of the protected folder?

Comment: Well I tried it with an encrypted password and it didn't work.
Just wondered if there was an option for better security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried it with an encrypted password and it didn't work.
The answer is no don't use an encrypted password.